# How long until modeled data from Consent Mode (Google Analytics 4) is accessible in reports?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Approx. 1 month ago I have implemented Google Consent Mode for Google Analytics and Google Ads on two websites.

To the best of my knowledge, the setups are meeting all necessary prerequesites for behavioral modeling (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11161109?hl=en&sjid=16857101366487115096-EU):

- The payload sent to GA is as expected and I am also receiving the correct traffic for users, who gave consent in the cookie banner.
- All data streams in the respective GA4-property operate on Consent Mode
- The websites surpass the necessary traffic tresholds for consented and unconsented hits.

Since more than 28 days have passed and the ML-model at Google should have enough data for training, I suspect that there might be any other unexpected problem.

**Is there any way to check whether there any issues concerning the training of the model?**
**From your experience, what is a "normal" time frame until modeled data appears in the reports?**

Thank you!

Comment: This is not of any help, just here to say that we are facing the exact same problem also. Our site has operated in consent mode for two weeks now, from all I can tell we've done everything right and are meeting the traffic prerequisites; but we don't see any modelled data and it's marked as unavailable in the "Reporting identity" screen.